# Screen sharing and video broadcasting switching error in agora

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, webrtc, agora.io, screensharing

So, I have been working on a project that uses agora's web sdk. I basically want to seamlessly switch back and forth between screen sharing and video broadcasting, audio shared in both cases.

Here's what I have coded:

```
const localPlay = {
    screen: {
        playing: false,
        initialised: false
    },
    video: {
        playing: false,
        initialised: false
    }
};


// Initialise two clients and two streams, with the following stream specs
 const screenStreamSpec = {
                streamID: uid,
                audio: false,
                video: false,
                screen: true,
            };

const videoStreamSpec = {
                streamID: uid,
                audio: true,
                video: true,
                screen: false,
            };

// ...

document.getElementById("Screen-share").addEventListener("click", function() {

    if(!localPlay.screen.initialised) {
        return
    } else {
        if(!localPlay.screen.playing && !localPlay.video.playing) {
            screenStream.play("Screen");
            rtc.client.screenClient.publish(screenStream);
            localPlay.screen.playing = true;                        
            return;
        }

        if(localPlay.screen.playing) {
            return;
        }

        videoStream.stop();
        localPlay.screen.playing = false;
        screenStream.play("Screen");
        localPlay.video.playing = true;

        let newTrack = videoStream.getVideoTrack();
        screenStream.replaceTrack(newTrack);
    }
});


document.getElementById("Video-share").addEventListener("click", function() {

    if(!localPlay.video.initialised) {
        return
    } else {
        if(!localPlay.video.playing && !localPlay.screen.playing) {
            videoStream.play("Screen");
            rtc.client.videoClient.publish(videoStream);
            localPlay.video.playing = true;
            return;
        }

        if(localPlay.video.playing) {
            return;
        }

        screenStream.stop();
        localPlay.video.playing = false;
        videoStream.play("Screen");
        localPlay.screen.playing = true;

        let newTrack = screenStream.getVideoTrack();
        videoStream.replaceTrack(newTrack);
    }
});
```

The code is in accordance with [this](https://docs.agora.io/en/faq/switch_screen_camera_web#solution-3-replace-the-current-video-track) (solution 3).

The error is that the first time I try to do either, they work. But, say if I started with screen sharing, and switch to video broadcasting, the cam turns off, screen sharing turns off, and the screen that I was sharing is rotated and displayed in the `Screen` div. If I try to switch one more time, the div goes totally black.

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should not be using replace track as its not supported by all browsers and a relatively new feature.

For a more stable solution I would suggest using 2 clients, one for the camera and a separate one for the screen share. I have an example here: https://github.com/digitallysavvy/group-video-chat

If you want to switch between the two quickly you could use the muteVideo events to toggle between the streams.

Comment: Hi @Hermes, could you please guide me that how can I extend the no of speakers beyond what agora supports in group video calls?